# Combining effects/filters using Pixastic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, pixastic

I was using Pixastic to change simple effects like brightness and contrast of an image on a canvas.

However, I have not been able to find a way to apply these effects together. E.g. Applying brightness then applying a contrast on this already brightened image, not the original image.

Using `Pixastic.revert(img);` does not work since it applies each effect to the original image instead of layering them.

I am not even sure this is possible with Pixastic since I have not been able to find a solution to this for weeks now.

Is there any other jquery plugin that does similar things like changing brightness and contrast of an image. I need to get this to work for IE9+ so my options are very limited. Most things seem to only work for Chrome/Opera/Safari etc.

Comment: Did you consider [CSS3](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html) instead of Canvas? CSS3 is much faster

Comment: Yes, I did, but it does not work for IE.

Comment: I have just tried applying brightness and contrast both together ( `Pixastic.process(img, "brightness", {brightness:50,contrast:0.5});` ), and it seems to work fine. The same goes to calling `process` method twice with differect arguments. There is an example on [this page](http://dph.am/pixastic-docs/docs/actions/brightness/).

Comment: I saw that, but I couldn't find a way to use that with range sliders. For example, if I slide to brightness 20 and then to 10, it applies brightness of 10 to the already brightened image instead of bringing it down to 10. And revert removes say, a contrast and lighten effect I applied before the brightness effect. 
Even if I note down what the value of the contrast slider and the value of the lightness slider is, the order they were applied in makes a difference. So I need to keep track of this order as well.

Comment: Now I understand you :) When I faced the same problem, I solved it a bit different way. Instead of range sliders I used buttons "add more contrast", "add more brightness", ..., and finally "revert all". Of course, range sliders would be much better, but in my case the above solution was acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/).

On their [docs](http://camanjs.com/api/) there is the following example:

```
Caman("#image-id", function () {
  this.brightness(10);
  this.contrast(20);
  this.render(function () {
    alert("Done!");
  });
});
```

This library uses a hidden canvas, and after rendering, it resets `src` attribure of `img` tag in `base64` format.

And yes, it works with IE9+

You can view examples [here](http://camanjs.com/examples/).

Comment: Yes, I have tried CamanJS as well. Unfortunately, it is extremely slow. :(